# how do i check the number of 1 inside the top left corner to bottom right of my 5x5 matrix

Tags: matlab

```
input = input('Please enter a number between 1 to 5: ');
counter = 0;    
mat= zeros(5,5)

if input == 1 
   while mat(1)~= 1 && mat(7)~= 1 && mat(13)~= 1 && mat(19)~= 1 && mat(25) ~= 1  
      mat= randi (10,5); 
      counter = counter +1;
   end
   a = mat
   fprintf('%d matrices were generated to find a good one\n', counter )
end
```

I can make the system to check the diagonal path to only contain 1 '1' to fulfill the requirement. however,

How do i make the system to check the diagonal path to contain 2 or 3 or 4 '1'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`diag`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/diag.html) for this. To find how many elements on the diagonal are 4, you can do:

```
sum(diag(A) == 4)
```

If you want to know if it contains exactly 2 `1`'s, then you can do: `(sum(diag(A) == 1) == 2)`.

`diag` returns the diagonal of a matrix. `diag(A) == 4` returns a logical vector with 1 where the diagonal is 4, and 0 all other places. By summing all the 1's, you can find the total number of 4's.

Comment: ohh i see, thanks. i solved the problem, but just one question, what does the ==2) of the ==1)==2) means?

Comment: @Dicksontan: The first one checks which elements of the diagonal are equal `1`, while the second one checks if the number (sum) of `1`'s is 2. If you want to know if there is exactly one `4` in the diagonal you would have: `sum(diag(A) == 4) == 1`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Dicksontan Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem (tick mark on the upper left corner of the answer)